# Error: pure virtual method called - terminate called without an active exception - Aborted

Tags: c++

In my A.h file:

```
class A{
  private:
    unsigned short PC;
  public:
    A():PC(0){}
    virtual ~A(){}
    virtual void execute(unsigned short PC)=0;
};
```

In my B.h file:

```
class B:public A{
  private: 
      int status;bool exe;
  public:
    B:status(0),exe(false){}
    virtual B(){}
    void execute (unsigned short PC);
};
```

In my B.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

void B::execute (unsigned short PC){
  cout << "Run";
}
```

In my Functions.h file :

```
#include "A.h"

class Functions{
  public: 
    int status;
    Functions():status(1){} // this is a constructer
    void run(A *a);
};
```

IN my Functions.cpp file:

```
#include "Functions.h"
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;
void Functions::run (A *a){
  a->execute();
}
```

In my Main.cpp file:

```
#include "A.h" 
#include "B.h" 

int main(int args, char**argv){
  A *a;
  B b;
  a = &b;
  Functions f;
  f.run(a);
  return 1;
}
```

When I run , it has some error:
**pure virtual method called -  terminate called without an active exception -  Aborted**
Can anybody where did I misunderstand?
Thank you

Comment: That code has numerous errors that prevent it from compiling. That means it isn't the code that's causing your problem, and instead an attempt to mock up something resembling the code that's causing your problem. And that means the mock up (even if all the errors were fixed) might not cause your problem. In fact, it doesn't look like it would cause the problem you're seeing. If you're going to post mock-up code, test that code first to make sure it causes the same problem as the original code.

Comment: to get good answers please post actual code or snippets that make sense

Comment: @Marius Bancila: Posting snippets for a runtime problem is only useful in the minority of cases. Actual compilable code that demonstrates the problem is what is really needed.

Comment: sure, won't argue with that. but even snippet are actually better than code with lots of obvious errors

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usually you get this error when call your virtual function from constructor or destructor.
Check that that is not the case.

(I assume that your demo code is not complete).

Comment: Or you call method while object is destructing. Read here: http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/gcc-pure-virtual-method-called/

Comment: Thank you, I called a function from constructor and then the function called a virtual function. Okay, this is a problem because you still can be in the process of creating an object for a base class while you want to call a virtual function which should be called for the non-existing object of a derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you're doing but this, which is basically what you're showing us, except that is simplified and actually compiling, runs without any problems:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
   virtual ~A() {}
   virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
   virtual void execute() {std::cout << "B::execute" << std::endl;}
};

void execute(A* a)
{
   a->execute();
}

int main()
{
   A* a;
   B b;
   a = &b;

   execute(a);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote B() constructor without paranthesis , plus you have 2 B() default constructors, plus one of them is virtual(not good), plus when you execute a->execute, again you need paranthesis with an argument, because it is a function:

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
private:
unsigned short PC;
public:
A():PC(0){}
virtual ~A(){}
virtual void execute(unsigned short PC)=0;
};


class B:public A{
private:
    int status;
    bool exe;
public:
B():status(0),exe(false){}
//virtual B(){}
void execute (unsigned short PC);
};



void B::execute (unsigned short PC){
cout << "Run";
}



class Functions{
public: int status;
Functions():status(1){} // this is a constructer
void run(A *a);
};


void Functions::run (A *a){
a->execute(1);
}


int main(int args, char**argv){
A *a;
B b;
a = &b;
Functions f;
f.run(a);
return 1;
}
```

Comment: I execute on my comp, and i didnt get errors, it prints: "Run".

Comment: void Functions::run (A *a){
a->execute(1);
} 1?

Comment: well you are asking for an usigned short, so i just put 1 to compile

Comment: ah, sorry, i still don't know why it doesn't work on my computer. Everything is the same.

Comment: pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
Same error as the beginning :(

Comment: did you copy paste the code or did you fix all the errors that i told you ?

Comment: copy paste the code i gave you, and tell me then if you still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int args, char**argv){
    A *a;
    B b; // wrong
    a = &b; // wrong
    Functions f;
    f.run(a);
    return 1;
}
```

you can do this :

```
int main(int args, char**argv){
    A *a = new B;
    //B b;
    //a = &b;
    Functions f;
    f.run(a);
    return 1;
}
```