# Error: pure virtual method called

Tags: c++

In my AC.h file:

```
#ifndef _AC_H
#define _AC_H
class AC{
private:
    unsigned short PC;
public:
    AC():PC(0){}
    virtual ~AC(){}
    virtual void test()=0;
};
#endif
```

In my R500.h file:

```
#ifndef _R500_H
#define _R500_H
#include <iostream>
#include "AC.h"
class R500:public AC{
private: int mCStatus;
public:
    R500():mCStatus(0){}
    virtual ~R500(){}
    void test();
};
#endif
```

In my R500.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "R500.h"
using namespace std;
void R500::test(){
    cout << "test called\n";
}
```

In my AF.h file

```
#ifndef _AF_H
#define _AF_H
#include "AC.h"
class AF{
public: int status;
    AC *ac;
    AF():status(1){} // this is a constructer
    void menu();
    void run();
};
#endif
```

In my AF.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "R500.h"
#include "AF.h"
#include "AC.h"

using namespace std;
void AF::menu() {
    R500 r;
    ac = &r;
    run();
}

void AF::run() {
    ac->test();
}
```

In my Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AF.h"
#include "R500.h"
#include "AC.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int args, char**argv){
    AF af;
    af.menu();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiled well but when I run, it said that 
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
Can anybody tell me where were I wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I was positive I saw this question a couple days ago with different non-real code, but I can't find it now.

Comment: typing mistake, sorry ... I already had AF():status(1){} // this is a constructer

Comment: Found the probable dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407304/error-pure-virtual-method-called-terminate-called-without-an-active-exception

Answer (score 6):

`</Telepathy mode:on>`

Somewhere in your code (which you didn't posted apparently) you've called virtual function from constructor or destructor. This function have happened to be *pure* virtual in class which constructor/destructor you called it from.

You've got `pure virtual call` because at that point of time, full sub-object was either not fully constructed yet, or already destroyed. And with full sub-object was destroyed its virtual function table. So you was left with virtual function table from your abstract class, and via this table you've called *pure* virtual function.

Check also this link: [When my base class's constructor calls a virtual function on its this object, why doesn't my derived class's override of that virtual function get invoked?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5)

Comment: Or he's slicing. Or mixing up his global/member/local variables.

Comment: I don't believe compiler would pass slicing to the sub-object of abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of `AC *ac;`
One in AF class defined in AF.h and another one with global scope in AF.cpp.
The code you posted is not exactly the one leading to the issue so it's hard to tell you more.

Comment: this is the real code, and the ac variable in AF.cpp, that's a typing mistake, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

There is several things that can be improved in your code.

But for your question, this code compiles and runs fine on Visual Studio 2008 :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AC 
{
private:
    unsigned short PC;
public:
    AC():PC(0) {}
    virtual ~AC() {}
    virtual void test() = 0;
};

class R500 : public AC
{
private: 
    int mCStatus;
public:
    R500(): mCStatus(0) {}
    virtual ~R500() {}
    void test();
};

void R500::test()
{
    cout << "test called\n";
}

class AF
{
public: 
    int status;
    AC *ac;
    AF() : status(1) {} // You forgot to add a body to your constructor here "{}"
    void menu();
    void run();
};

void AF::menu() 
{
    R500 r;
    ac = &r;
    run();
}

void AF::run() 
{
    ac->test();
}

int main(int args, char** argv)
{
    AF af;
    af.menu();
    return 0;
}
```

The only two things that I did are :

- Add a body to the constructor of AF
- Remove the global variable ac

Answer (score 0):

Background: When constructing a C++ object, you first construct the base-class, then each intermediate class in turn, finishing with the concrete class. While each layer is constructed, it only has access to virtual functions that itself, or superclasses, have defined. The same mechanism take place when the object is destroyed, albeit reversed.

If the a constructor/destructor calls a virtual function that only is defined by a subclass, you will trigger the *pure virtual function called* error, which will immediate abort your program.