# pure virtual method called error

Tags: c++, exception, virtual-functions

I have the following definitions:

```
class PartitioningMethod {
public:
  virtual void addConstraints(ConstraintManager& cm) = 0;
  virtual bool hasMoreConstraints() = 0;
  virtual void setQuery(const Query& q) = 0;
  virtual ~PartitioningMethod(){ }
};


class Random : public PartitioningMethod {
private:
  vector< ref<Expr> > constraints;
  vector< ref<Expr> >::iterator it;
  vector< ref<Expr> >::iterator end;
  int numConstraints;
  RNG theRNG;

public:
  void setQuery(const Query& q) { 

    constraints.clear();

    //Set random number
    //srand ( unsigned ( time (NULL) ) * theRNG.getInt32() );
    srand ( theRNG.getInt32() );

    //Copy constraints    
    copy(q.constraints.begin(),q.constraints.end(),std::back_inserter(constraints));

    //Shuffle Randomly
    std::random_shuffle(constraints.begin(),constraints.end(), p_myrandom);

    it = constraints.begin();
    end = constraints.end();
    numConstraints = constraints.size();
  }

  void addConstraints(ConstraintManager& cm) {
    int step = rand() % numConstraints + 1;
    while(step != 0) {
      cm.addConstraint(*it);
      ++it;
      --step;
      --numConstraints;
    }   
  }

  bool hasMoreConstraints() {
    return it != end;
  }
};


bool PartitioningSolver::computeInitialValues(const Query& query,
                            const std::vector<const Array*> &objects,
                            std::vector< std::vector<unsigned char> > &values,
                            bool &hasSolution) {

  fprintf(stderr,"INIT\n");  
  // If there are no constraints in the query
  if(query.constraints.size() == 0 || query.constraints.size() == 1)
    return solver->impl->computeInitialValues(query, objects, values, hasSolution);

  // If the number constraints in the query are > 0 
  method->setQuery(query);

  ConstraintManager cm;
  ref<Expr> expr = query.expr;

  fprintf(stderr,"Begin partitioning\n");
  fprintf(stderr,"---------------------\n");  

  while(method->hasMoreConstraints()){
    fprintf(stderr, "HERE");
    //Add Constraints
    method->addConstraints(cm);

    //Construct a query
    Query temp_query(cm,expr);

     ExprPPrinter::printQuery(std::cerr,temp_query.constraints,temp_query.expr); 
     fprintf(stderr,"---------------------\n");

    //Query STP to check if satisfiable
    values.clear(); 

    if(!solver->impl->computeInitialValues(temp_query, objects, values, hasSolution))
      return false;

    //If not, return immediately (a win!) 
    if(!hasSolution)
      return true; 

    //If a solution is returned, check if the solution satisfies the entire set of constraints
    vector<const Array*> obj = objects;
    Assignment solution(obj, values);
    bool satisfiesAll = checkSolution(solution, query.constraints);

    //  fprintf(stderr,"Satisfies all: %i\n", satisfiesAll);

    // If it is successful, return the solution (a win again!), 
    if(satisfiesAll)
      return true;

    // If not add more constraints (if there is more) and repeat
  }
  return true;
}
```

A Partial definition for the Partitioning solver class:

```
class PartitioningSolver : public SolverImpl {
private:
  Solver*             solver;
  PartitioningMethod* method;
  bool checkSolution(Assignment& solution,  const ConstraintManager& constraints);  
public:
  PartitioningSolver(Solver *s,  PartitioningMethod* pm) : solver(s), method(pm) { }
  ~PartitioningSolver() { delete solver; delete method; }
};
```

Sorry for pasting such a long snippet of code but I have been working on it for hours and keep getting the eror

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

I am not sure what's wrong. It seems to fail in computeInitialValues function where `fprintf(stderr,"Begin partitioning\n");` is located. I tried adding print statements as a last resort but even they don't print anything.. Any ideas is appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok so I changed the name Random to Ran and it started to work. I was creating this class instance on the fly as an argument with new Random() I guess it was mixing up with another constructor or something else I dont know..

Comment: yes why is it happening any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Due to the various limitations of the codebase I am unable to use a debugger. I basically can't compile it with -g option for gdb or other tools

Comment: @Cemre: What limitations exactly are keeping you from using a debugger/compiling with debug informations? I'm really curious. Furthermore: I would say that your error is very likely to be that you called a pure virtual method somewhere (thats what the error message says afterall), so why do you need us to look for that?

Comment: Delete code until it starts working.

Comment: How are Solver and Assignment defined? Are they abstract interfaces too? If so, what do your derived implementations look like?

Comment: @ceretullis no they are concrete classes. The confusing thing is I also have other classes defined similar to Random (they are just doing different a type of operation) and they are working fine. I am not sure what's wrong with this one.

Comment: What I was getting at was, how do you know for sure the problem is with this class unless you have a call stack in the debugger? From what I'm seeing, I don't think your fprint tracing is prolific enough for you to say for sure the problem is this class. I'd comment out everything in your implementation, run it make sure you don't get the error, then start adding functionality back in until it breaks.

Comment: Try very hard indeed to fix the debugging issue else you will be posting here continually with questions we can't answer except with speculation:(

Comment: Ok so I changed the name Random to Ran and it started to work. I was creating this class instance on the fly as an argument with `new Random()` I guess it was mixing up with another constructor or something else I dont know..

Comment: Possibly related: [Error: pure virtual method called - terminate called without an active exception - Aborted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5407304) and [Pure virtual method called error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12044819).

Answer (score 11):

There's another type of bug, which can cause this error message to be printed.

You deleted the object, and later you're trying to make a call on it. It's undefined behaviour, and on some compilers, if you're lucky, that's what you'll see. Try to run your code with valgrind.

http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/gcc-pure-virtual-method-called/

Comment: I tried using valgrind but for some reason it doesn't print an error message for this error.. I just get the crash output and that's it

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a pure virtual function from a constructor in some code that you haven't included for us to see.

[When my base class's constructor calls a virtual function on its this object, why doesn't my derived class's override of that virtual function get invoked?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5)