# pure virtual method called, terminate called without an active exception, pthreads, opencv

Tags: c++, pthreads

My code has the following basic structure,

```
pthread_t worker, processor; 

int i = 0;

int main(..) {

    pthread_create(worker,NULL,loop,NULL);

    char inp;
    cin >> inp;
    while(inp != 'q') {
        cin >> inp;
    }

    i = 1;

    pthread_join(processor,NULL);
    pthread_join(worker,NULL);

    return 0;

}

void *loop(..) {

    while(i==0) {
        //do stuff
        pthread_join(processor,NULL);
        pthread_create(processor,NULL,process,NULL);

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *process(..) {

    //do stuff
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Everything works as it should except when i press 'q' i get,

pure virtual method called, terminate called without an active exception

just before it exits. I don't understand why because i'm joining all the threads i created before i exit. Help!!

I'm running it on a debian(armhf) with gcc

**EDIT:**  I tried above sample without my opencv stuff and there is no problem. So i believe i've asked the wrong question. 
In gdb i can see whatever the first call i make to the opencv (3.0.0) API generates 8 threads. And they never exit.
Is it possible that these threads are not joined prior exiting? I'm not sure how to make them join either because i'm not the one creating them.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, because it's impossible to say anything with the code you show us. Especially since you don't seem to have any abstract classes?

Comment: From `pthread_join` documentation "*If multiple threads simultaneously try to join with the same thread, the results are undefined.*"

Comment: the actual code is quite large. i'll try to minimize it. this is actually an opencv application and on gdb i noticed that opencv is starting some threads too. And no i don't use any abstract classes.

Comment: You _do_ use some abstract class somewhere - it may not be YOUR class, but there is one somewhere. Guaranteed. The error is very specific, and its only reasonable source is the compiler-generated code for an abstract member function being called. Possibly because of something else wrong, like your code creating a base-class when it should create a derived class. Of course, there's a small chance that your code is hitting something undefined and that causes the problem, but that's like a novice archer hitting bulls-eye when blindfolded...

Comment: @MatsPetersson you're right. It must be in the opencv code :) i wish i could post the complete code here but it's work related so i cannot. perhaps an opencv expert can tell me how to make it's threads exit properly? there is no issue whatsoever with the operation of the program. Only when the program exits i gets this error. Specifically, when i call return 0.

Comment: Possibly related: [Error: pure virtual method called - terminate called without an active exception - Aborted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5407304) and [Pure virtual method called error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12044819).